# Render Template Rust Rocket Handlebars

Tags: rust, rocket

I am trying to render a template with rust rocket and handlebars, this works fine but I can't get any arguments to the html file to work, the page loads, but the argument is not there. I am familiar with flask and jinja for python but not as much with rocket and handlebars. I have tried countless things but I can't find any documentation that works.

**main.rs**

```
#![feature(decl_macro)]

extern crate rocket;
extern crate rocket_contrib;

use rocket::{get, routes};
use rocket_contrib::templates::Template;


#[get("/one")]
fn one() -> String {
    format!("One")
}


#[get("/page")]
fn page() -> Template {
    let context = "string";
    Template::render("page", &context)
}


fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", routes![one])
        .attach(Template::fairing())
        .launch();
}
```

**page.html.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Argument is: {{context}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template system doesn't know that the local variable is called `context`. It just knows that your context is a string, which doesn't have an attribute called `context`. You need to provide a type implementing `Serialize`, with a member called `context` for the template expression `{{context}}` to expand to anything.  You could do this with a `HashMap` or a custom type.

With a `HashMap`:

```
#[get("/page")]
fn page() -> Template {
    let mut context = HashMap::new();
    context.insert("context", "string");
    Template::render("page", &context)
}
```

With a custom type:

```
#[get("/page")]
fn page() -> Template {
    #[derive(serde_derive::Serialize)]
    struct PageContext {
        pub context: String,
    }

    let context = PageContext { context: "string" };
    Template::render("page", &context)
}
```

Custom types will generally perform better, and are self-documenting.